# Using Font Awesome CDN

Tags: embed, font-awesome, cdn

I am wondering why you get a unique embed code every time for using Font Awesome CDN. Is there any downside to using the same embed code multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create account on their CDN service, which gives you access to some additional features and simplification tools, like specifying which Font Awesome version will be served to your users or cache invalidation if served version is changed.

Since they don't have users functionality on their main page, and they don't do user tracking, they have no way of knowing whether requested embed code will be used by new user or by existing user on new site. To save you hassle of creating multiple account on CDN service and to allow you management of all installations from one page, they ask you to always give the same email address, but they send you unique embed codes each time.

There are no downsides of using one embed code on multiple sites as long as you want the same configuration on all sites. If, for whatever reason, you want one site to use different version than your second site, you should use separate embed codes.

Answer (score 0):

Browser caching.  If new fonts are added they won't show on the client unless they do a forced refresh.